# What's the best practice of reporting answers which include exactly the same code as in the question?

Tags: discussion, answers, flags

While searching for an answer to a JavaScript question, I came across an answer which simply posted the same code which the OP had included in the question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13399692/5798798

What is the best way to report this? Should I flag it as 'not an answer', or a custom flag?

Comment: In this particular case since neither accepted answer nor one you are talking about do not actually answer the question ("Why standard way of blocking default browser click on HREF does not work") you may want to provide your own answer (or suggest duplicate as you probably found more than one).

Comment: If the answer were nothing more than a copy-and-paste of the code in the question, I'd be very tempted to call it Not An Answer. But the code in the answer is merely *equivalent* to the code in the question (the answer's code is more generic), and it includes a description. It is an answer, and it's incorrect. (It's 5+ years old and currently has 9 downvotes and one delete vote, with a comment explaining the situation, so I'm not inclined to pile on with another downvote.) And there's an accepted answer too.

Answer (score 14):

It's not "not an answer".  It's an attempt to answer the question, it's just a really bad answer that *fails* in its attempt to answer the question.  When an answer is wrong, or bad, you don't flag it at all.  You use a downvote to indicate that you don't think an answer is useful.

If you think you can help the author of the post fix it and turn it into a useful answer, you can also comment with how they could improve it.

Comment: Actually answering the question would be an improvement then, yes...

Comment: @usr2564301 I don't really consider "delete the post and start over" to be particularly helpful.  I personally don't consider such a post salvageable.  If you want to hold the author's hand through the entire process of constructing a correct answer though, you're welcome to.

Comment: I don't think I want to be the person to tell that poster, "hey, but that's just the original code – here's what to change..." It *is* an (bad, bad attempt to) answer and as it's *not useful* in its current state, I'll just downvote it.

Comment: In this case Code posted by OP should work as requested. If you read whole question turned out MCVE was not provided and that code should work as an answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov And an answer saying that they couldn't reproduce the problem *would* be Not An Answer.  This isn't that though.  This is someone posting what they think is actually fixing a problem and providing an answer, but is in fact just re-posting what the OP has.

Comment: In general - yes, in this particular case I'm not so sure - answer provides answer to question stated in title and may be useful for future visitors as is. Indeed question itself should be closed as "missing MCVE" (or I voted as "no longer repro") or edited to clarify the problem (clearly OP knows how to achieve *what they are asking about*, but had problem with implementation - so question should be phrased differently). Side note: accepted answer to the question is equally unrelated to the problem...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov If you think that the answer isn't useful, you can downvote it, as I have said in my answer.  If you feel that the question doesn't contain enough information to be answered, then yes, by all means, vote to close.  But the question meriting closure doesn't make the answer NAA.  And I agree that the accepted answer is not a useful answer for the same reason this answer isn't useful, but neither answer is NAA.

Comment: In this case the answer was too old, but ideally you would flag a new answer like this as Very Low Quality, and then downvote and, if you wish, comment.

Comment: @TylerH VLQ isn't for answers that you think are wrong.  That would be an inappropriate flag for exactly the same reasons that NAA is wrong.  VLQ is for things that don't even resemble an answer.  It's not a "second downvote" for posts that you think are wrong.

Comment: @Servy Right, VLQ is for things that aren't worth posting, that don't provide anything useful, that an edit couldn't save/form into a useful answer. Repeating, verbatim, code from the question is such a case. Such an 'answer' is VLQ and is delete-worthy.

Comment: @TylerH No, VLQ is *not* for things that aren't useful.  Downvotes are for things that aren't useful.  VLQ is for things that aren't even answers.  Not for answers that you think aren't useful.  If you think it's not useful downvote.  Don't flag.

Comment: @Servy No, NAA is for things that aren't even answers. VLQ is for things whose quality is so low that it isn't worth keeping around, like an answer that just repeats some part of a question.

Comment: @TylerH VLQ is for things that are utterly incomprehensible, to the point that they're *not even answers*.  Not for *answers to the question* that you think aren't useful. Again, downvotes are specifically there to indicate that you think a post isn't useful.  VLQ isn't a second downvote.

Comment: @Servy not just incomprehensible, but also with severe *content problems*. Again, this is a VLQ answer, and should be deleted. You're free to disagree, though.

Comment: @TylerH No, the answer *isn't* VLQ.  It's not a matter of opinion.  A post isn't VLQ because  you think it's wrong.  The whole idea of flags is that they're not evaluating the technical merits of an answer.  That you think it's wrong doesn't make it VLQ.  If you think it's not useful downvote it.  Abusing flags because you want to do more than downvoting when a post only merits a downvote isn't appropriate.

Comment: You don't need domain knowledge to know the answer is an exact copy of the question without any change... (but yes, this was an attempt at answering)

Comment: @JohnDvorak It's not like it's a copy paste of the code in the question.  The code is different, it's just not *meaningfully* different.  Someone without knowledge of the subject matter won't necessarily know that the changes aren't fixing the problem.

Comment: @Servy I think it's VLQ because it's VLQ. This is my opinion, and yours is clearly different. Your flags are yours to use as you like, but it's not abuse to flag a VLQ answer as VLQ, and you saying otherwise is harmful to the health of this site. Good day.

Comment: Supplementary question then: would the answer be a good use of delete votes?

Comment: @TylerH Votes are highly subjective, and users are given wide latitude to express their own opinions of what they feel is useful or not useful when they cast their votes.  Flags are *far* less subjective.  You can't just saying that something is VLQ because you say so, and ignore the actual rules of the site.  It *is* abuse to flag a post as VLQ just because it's wrong, when it's actually posting an answer to the question.  That's not what the flag is for.  That's not an opinion, it's a policy.

Comment: I don't think it applies in this case, but before you get too heavy-handed with dissing an answer, do check whether the OP changed the question after the answer was written.

Comment: Ehrm.... how is `an answer which simply posted the same code which the OP had included in the question` even considered a attempt at an answer

Comment: @EpicKip The intention of the author of that answer appears to be that he was trying to answer the question. To me it looks like he came up with the same code as the question, simply because that code does work. He probably didn't pay enough attention to the code in the question when answering, but that doesn't make it no attempt to answer, so NAA shouldn't be used. However, since the answer isn't really a good one, and it isn't salvageable, it should probably be deleted anyways, so perhaps VLQ is a proper solution as TylerH mentioned.

Comment: @g00glen00b I can't see the answer (has been deleted I think) but if its the exact same code I wouldn't consider it an answer. If it is nearly the same but a few adjustments I would consider it an attempt

Comment: @g00glen00b I have a hard time believing that a *"code doesn't do what I want, how to make it do what I want?"* question is ever answered with *"code that does the same thing that you don't want"*. There's a section in the help center that says "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed".

Comment: @Braiam It the answer *fails* to answer the question.  That doesn't make it not an answer.  It's an *attempt* to answer the question.  It's just wrong.  We don't delete answers for being wrong.  We delete answers for *not even being answers*.  If you think an answer is wrong, the mechanism created for you to express that opinion is to downvote it.  There is not flag answer for, "this answer is incorrect", and for good reason.  There is in fact a flag decline template precisely to indicate that flags are not to be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, and that that's what votes are for.

Comment: @Servy we delete answers that doesn't **fundamentally answer the question**. I never said because they are wrong, just that doesn't answer the question. An answer that says the same thing that the asker doesn't want to do (without explaining why such thing is desirable) doesn't answers the question. We would not delete an answer that says 42 if the question is "what is the answer to the ultimate question of life the universe and everything", because it answers it. It can be wrong, mind you, but it answers the question.

Comment: @Braiam We delete answers that don't *attempt* to answer the question, not answers that attempt to, but fail, to answer the question.  A failed attempt at answering the question, in other words an incorrect answer, is still *an answer*.  The answer here, while incorrect, and not *successfully* answering the question, is still *an answer to the question*.  The author here is clearly *trying* to answer the question, they think that they have solved the OP's problem.  They're wrong, but that doesn't make it not an answer.

Comment: @Braiam The code in the question did what the OP wanted, so I'm able to believe that the answerer was confused by that and tried the code/changing/undoing his changes it and ended up with that answer. I'm not saying I wouldn't delete it though, but NAA isn't the choice I would take. I would either flag it for VLQ, or since this is a good example of a bad question attracting bad answer, I might just focus on the question in stead.

Comment: @g00glen00b see, that's different. I would say that instead of answering, asking the asker what exactly is wrong with his code would be more efficient, since it does what he wants.

Comment: Delete votes are given to those with subject matter expertise for a reason. If it is required that you have knowledge of the subject matter to understand that a post should be deleted, a delete vote would be appropriate. Though if it was truly a copy and paste job, I would have used a custom flag explaining that. VLQ is for absolute unarguable garbage, meaning that no matter who views the content, they would immediately agree that the post holds no value whatsoever. I don't believe this is such a case because it requires context and knowledge of the subject to know that it should be deleted.