# Technically off-topic answer, but seems to be helpful

Tags: discussion, answers

I came through the following question:

[How to set image name in Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986057/how-to-set-image-name-in-dockerfile)

It clearly asks for settings image name **in Dockerfile**.

The first answer completely answers the question, however, the second one doesn't seem to answer the question:

> How to build an image with custom name without using yml file:
>
> ```
> docker build -t image_name .
> ```
>
> How to run a container with custom name:
>
> ```
> docker run -d --name container_name image_name
> ```

There's an upvoted comment, which tells:

> I've come back to this a couple times, and this answer has helped, despite being technically off-topic

Both the comment and the upvotes on the answer indicate that the answer is really being helpful.

It could be that people who look for "how to build a Docker image" reaches this question, which is irrelevant, but the answer is helpful.

It didn't feel right to me to flag it, neither to downvote. What do you think should be done here?

Comment: I doubt there's much that *can* be done now beyond the comments acknowledging the nature of the answer.

Comment: Also, I found this deleted comment by the answerer: "for some applications it is. Its good to have comprehensive answers under a topic." Which seems absurd of course. A question about how to do something specific in a Dockerfile isn't an invitation to post answers about every aspect of Docker imaginable. Otherwise we'd just have a single question with millions of answers per topic.

Comment: *Both the comment and the upvotes on the answer indicate that the answer is really being helpful.* But do you agree that it's useful? You're allowed to disagree with the previous voters.

Comment: I can't find it now but there was a Meta question about what to do with answers that just repeat the code in the question. That would be relevant to this as well.

Comment: Found it. The current answer says that repeating the code in the question doesn't make it Not An Answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361317/whats-the-best-practice-of-reporting-answers-which-include-exactly-the-same-cod

Comment: It certainly is an answer. It just isn't the right answer. So flagging it as not an answer would just be wrong. You can downvote it if you wish (since it may be generally helpful, but it isn't helpful on that question). But I certainly wouldn't flag it, and I would personally leave it be.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Is it really a "wrong answer" if it answers a different question? In that case EVERY answer would fit as an answer to EVERY question, as long as it qualifies for an answer.

Comment: Yeah, as @klutt says, I don't think it's enough if an answer attempts to answer some question someone might have somewhere. It must be an attempt to answer *the* question it is posted as an answer to.

Comment: If we look at [this global meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/369403), Shog is pretty explicit that anything that is an answer, even if it's terrible, still is an answer and shouldn't be flagged as _not an answer_. I've had trouble with that concept and have had declined NAA flags, but this is what I currently believe. We can do very little but downvote answers that aren't applicable to the question, and delete vote if downvoted enough and if you have sufficient rep

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth That post does not talk about answers that don't address the question in any way.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth *"I've had trouble with that concept and have had declined NAA flags, but this is what I currently believe."* In my experience, NAA flags on posts that don't address the question tend to get resolved in favor of the flag by both review and moderators if you make clear what the problem is, e.g. with a comment. Fwiw, my post flag stats are 7.1k helpful, 8 declined.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth An answer like 3 + 3 = 5 is certainly *not* an answer to the question "why chose technology x?". Being it a terrible (quality!!) answer means downvoting, being it not an *answer to the question* means a flag.

Comment: If this is an isolated case, leave it be. The answer has apparently been useful to a number of people.

Comment: I believe answers can be moved using a tool. Perhaps a more suitable question could be found?

Comment: @HimBromBeere The NaA flag should be used for things that are not answers _at all_. It should not be used for answers that were posted to the wrong question, nor answers that are technically inaccurate or altogether wrong.

Comment: @Tiny Giant: Answers cannot be moved.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth "Shog is pretty explicit that anything that is an answer, even if it's terrible, still is an answer and shouldn't be flagged as not an answer" where? The only thing I read is "if the text of the post contains an honest attempt at answering **the** question", not any question, not a question, but the question in... question.

Comment: @Braiam I hadn't considered that someone might _purposefully_ answer a different question. I considered this answer to be someone that made an honest attempt to answer the question, but just completely misunderstood the question, and thus fall under that category.

Comment: @Erik von Asmuth: The comment from the author that I quoted in my second comment above suggests that it was completely intentional.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I can see both readings, in this particular case.  I certainly have seen people say, "You might also be interested in an answer to [this question] as well:" and I've also seen, "I think that what you're actually asking is [this question].  If so:".  This answer doesn't explicitly indicate which they meant when they opened their answer with the question. Both seem plausible.

Comment: That's the first link I got in Google when I searched: "set image name build docker", **and** that answer **was** what I'm actually looking for. That's why I'm unsure if deleting the answers is the right action to do.

Comment: @BoltClock Ah, that makes it a different case (why someone would do that is a mystery to me). Then I'm all for removing that answer! (Either through NAA or otherwise). Someone could perhaps maybe create a self-answered community wiki and cite the user to preserve the content before it is lost to <10K users.

Comment: @Maroun If the information is useful, then even if you do delete it, you'd want to re-create it in an appropriate manner first, as described in my answer.

Comment: @Servy Technically, that's this seems to be the correct thing to do. But in real life, many users (including me), are reaching the answer from the first link in Google...

Comment: @Maroun Sure, because a better question apparently doesn't exist.  So *create that better question* so that people *aren't* directed to the wrong question when they have that problem.  You can also link to the new question in the comments so that if others still come across the old question they can find a question asking about the problem that they actually have.

Comment: @Servy I feel the need to post a question with an answer now..

Comment: @Maroun: Then the question remains, what of this answer? Also, what if people keep landing on this question despite your best efforts at creating a Q&A where the answer actually belongs? I mean, there's probably a reason why this question has nearly 40k views...

Comment: @boltclock i believe it is a cm tool, i've seen shog do it here on meta.

Comment: @BoltClock Could be left as is, or downvoted in the worst case. When a new question will be available, it could be added as a comment to this answer, and maybe OP will delete it.

Comment: @Tiny Giant: Not sure this is something I would hassle a CM about, but they might disagree...

Comment: @BoltClock You can (and should) have a comment linking to the related question, which would also add it to the "linked questions" in the sidebar, helping people find the new question even if the old question still manages to top it in SEO for that question.

Comment: Well, if you gotta break some egg shells to make the internet a better place, sobeit. @BoltClock

Comment: Deleting an answer that is currently making tye internet better because "rules" seems horribly short-sighted, and leaving it as is is just messy. The only soution i see is to find or ask a better question then move the answer.

Comment: I posted a new one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48172869/how-to-build-an-image-with-a-custom-name/48172870#48172870). Hopefully it will be helpful in the long term. But I'm not sure it's on-topic...

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth We can never know if a user actually *attempted* to answer the particular question.

Comment: I'd say this has everything to do with this being the first result if you put in "name docker image" in google. So unless/until you can replace it as the first result, any new question won't serve the same purpose. And, since the question preview *includes how to do it*, I'd be surprised if most hits even click through to SO.

Answer (score 4):

This answer should be posted under a question that it actually answers, rather than being posted to an entirely off topic question.  If there's a need for a question that explains how to build an image with custom name without using yml file, then ask a question that asks, "How to build an image with custom name without using yml file?", with that answer under it.  You could post a comment linking to that related question from the question it was originally posted under,
if people going to that question might be interested in the other question.

Comment: So, delete the answer?

Comment: @Braiam I'm still undecided on that one.  Ideally the author would do all of this, and delete the answer as a part of it.  It seems borderline as to whether the answer merits moderator deletion.  I lean towards it probably doesn't, but only just, but I could understand someone interpreting things such that they went the other way.

Comment: @Braiam More specifically, I could imagine someone interpreting that answer's opening sentence as acknowledging that they are trying to answer a different question than the one asked, which would make it merit deletion (as it's not even *trying* to answer the question).  I could also imagine someone interpreting it as the answer indicating that that's what they think the question is asking, which would make it not merit deletion.  I do think it would be appropriate for 20k users to vote to delete it, but as it needs to be negatively scored for that to happen, that's a non-factor.

Comment: @Braiam While the answer is not relevant to the specific question, people seem to reach it without looking for "Dockerfile". I'm not sure if deleting it is the correct thing to do.

Comment: @Maroun If people are being directed to an off topic question, because that's the only place that has an answer to this question, then *that's a problem*.  We want people looking for how to build an image with a custom name without using a yml file to find a question *actually asking that* that has their answer, not a question asking something unrelated that has the answer.  If the answer is only on an off topic question than lots of people will see that the question isn't asking what they want to solve and so not read the answers.

Comment: @Servy I'll have to agree.

Answer (score 1):

If there is already a good answer that answers the question, it is sometimes ok to add a complimentary one, which doesn't directly answer the question but adds additional important details to the topic. I can't tell if this is the case here, since I don't know the topic.

When posting such a complimentary answer, it is good practice to start with something like "*nn* has already answered the question, but...". This indicates that the post does in fact not answer the question directly, as it was stated. But such complimentary answers still have to be *on-topic*.

Examples of complimentary answers that could be ok:

- An example of why the accepted answer, although it answers the question, is bad or non-recommended practice in real applications.
- An answer that points out things to consider or things that can go wrong when using the method proposed in the accepted answer.
- An answer that offers an alternative method to what the question was asking for. It could perhaps suggest to do something else entirely, instead of what the OP was asking for. This could be appropriate for some "XY questions".
- A late answer that clarifies how the question/accepted answer is no longer relevant because the method used has gone obsolete since the point when the question was asked.

As a rule of thumb, if something could have been added to the accepted answer in the form of an intrusive edit (which is not ok), then it would probably make a good complimentary answer instead.

Example of complimentary answers that are not ok (not an answer, quite possibly spam):

- "Oh I see you posted a question about technology x. When working with technology x, here is some generic good advice: ..."
- A complementary link-only answer to documentation or resources. These should be posted as comments, if at all.

Comment: A complimentary answer still takes the question into account somehow, and that applies to each of these examples, even the XY question ones (provided they explicitly acknowledge this about the question). The kind of answer this question is referring to, is one that's so far off it might as well have been posted under the wrong question by mistake; the problem being described is that people are somehow not only discovering the answer despite having no real connection to the question, but also finding it helpful, thanks in probably no small part to the weird and wonderful world of web searches.

Comment: @BoltClock In that case it seems it falls into the category of "here is some generic good advise". Is that answer worth preserving? (I really can't tell, and I wouldn't trust the number of up-votes.) If it is helpful, maybe someone could post a new, different question and have the answer exported there?

Comment: The first, second, and fourth options you list are just commentary on another answer, and are NAA.  The should be posted as comments to the posts they're replying to.  The third is *an answer to the question*, just not necessarily the one that the OP was expecting, which is fine.

Comment: @Servy It is not always possible to post comments. You may need to write plenty of text. You may need to post code examples, for which comments are entirely unsuitable. And so on. A strict, bureaucratic black & white attitude that everything must always be an answer to the question, is not helpful and leads to worse technical quality of the content posted on the site. Quite often the OP asks about something which is a bad idea. The site benefits from showing the OP why it is a bad idea, not by teaching them how to carry out stupid things by answering the question.

Comment: @Lundin That's exactly the attitude that most sites other than SO take; that you shouldn't separate out answers from commentary on other posts.  SO make the explicit choice before it was even created that that caused way more problems than it solved, and that answers should be posted as answers, while commentary on other posts should be separated out.  As I said before, if you want to provide a different solution to the problem, your third option, that's an answer, but just commentary on other answers is not, and has its own place.